# Firebase Storage vs Database for Game Data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have multiple games developed, simple ones, all of them with local storage. When the user starts the app, I create a local_user.dat file in Documents Directory and update it when user gets more currency, buys skins, etc.

If the user deletes the app and installs it again later, he will lose all its progress. Kinda obvious. So, in order to avoid this, I want to store data online. In case he deletes the app, I will have a backup on server. When the user will reinstall the app, I will download the backup file instead of starting from zero

After a little search, I saw that Firebase can handle this for me. My question is which one of these 2 methods are more efficient for me and why.

Here is a part of my local_user.dat :

```
  "song_1_cost" : 100,
  "quote_2_owned" : false,
  "sound_on" : true,
  "song_11_owned" : false,
  "song_3_cost" : 250,
  "skin_2_cost" : 200,
  "song_5_cost" : 100,
  "song_equipped" : 0,
  "skin_4_cost" : 500,
  "song_7_cost" : 250,
  "quote_1_cost" : 100,
  "quote_4_cost" : 200,
  "song_9_cost" : 100,
  "quotes_equipped" : 1,
  "shuffle_enabled" : false,
  "song_12_cost" : 250,
  "tutorial" : true,
  "game_center_enabled" : false,
  "zen_level" : 1, etc
```

My local_user.dat can vary, from containing 30 keys to 100 keys and it's size average is 1.5 kb.

Which of these 2 features would be more optimal for my games?

- Storage - save my local_user.dat to firebase storage and replace it constantly with the updated version
- Database - create json with user data and :

  1. update the whole json
  2. update the json keys that modified

Comment: What would you recommend me to use in order to save data online?

Answer (score 1):

Both the Realtime Database and Cloud Storage can work for your scenario. The advantage of storing it in the database would be that you can query/access specific elements in the game data for a user, for example just their `zen_level` value.

If that is not required for your use-case (it doesn't seem to be), I'd probably pick the cheaper or simpler option (based on your non-functional requirements). Cloud Storage is definitely cheaper, precisely because it doesn't provide the same functionality as the database.